# Angular Js updating view in an event not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking to build an book shelf application which add, removes, edits books shelf data using angular routing.

But when I try to prepopulate a record to edit it, I'm not able to get the prepopulated values.

I have tried to assign value using `$scope.{model name}`. but it is not working

App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/viewBook',
                        { template : '<div ng-controller="ViewBookController"> <h2>Books</h2> <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"> <thead> <tr> <td>Name</td> <td>Category</td> <td>Price</td> <td>Actions</td> </tr> </thead> <tr ng-repeat ="book in books"> <td>{{book.name}}</td> <td>{{book.category}}</td> <td>{{book.price}}</td> <td><a href="#/addBook" ng-click="edit(addBook,book.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Edit</span></a> | <a href="#" ng-click="delete(book.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</span></a> </td> </tr> </table> </div>',
                          controller : 'ViewBookController'}).
                   when('/addBook', 
                        { template : '<div ng-controller = "ViewBookController"> <form class="well"> <label>Name*</label> <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="addBook.name" /><br/> <label>Category*</label> <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="addBook.category" /><br/> <label>Price*</label> <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="addBook.price" /><br/> <br/> <input type="hidden" ng-model="addBook.id"/> <button ng-click ="add(addBook)"><a href="#/viewBook">Add </button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#/viewBook">Cancel</a></button> </form> </div> ',
                          controller : 'ViewBookController'}).
                   otherwise({redirectTo: '/viewBook'});       

}]);

myApp.controller('ViewBookController', function($scope, ViewBookService) {   
     $scope.tempbook ="";  
    $scope.books = ViewBookService.list();
    $scope.delete = function (id) {
        ViewBookService.delete(id);
      //  if ($scope.addBook.id == id) 
      //  $scope.addBook = {};
    }

    $scope.add = function() {
        ViewBookService.save($scope.addBook);
        $scope.addBook = {};
        alert('book added successfully');
    }
     $scope.edit = function (addBook,id) {

          //$scope.addbook = $scope.tempbook; 

$scope.addBook= (angular.copy(ViewBookService.get(id)));


    }


});

myApp.service('ViewBookService', function() {
    //to create unique book id
    var uid = 3;

    //books array to hold list of all books

    var books = [{
            id : 0,
            name : 'Java',
            category : 'software',
            price : 600,
    },
    {
            id : 1,
            name : 'Sherlock Holmes',
            category : 'fiction',
            price : 350,
    },
    {
            id : 2,
            name : 'Wings of Fire',
            category : 'autobiography',
            price : 250,
    }];
//save method create a new book if doesnt exist else update the existing object
    this.save = function(book) {
        if(book.id == null) {
            book.id =uid++;
            books.push(book)
        }
        else {
            for(i in books) {
                if(books[i].id == book.id) {
                    books[i] ==book;
                }
            }
        }
    }

 //simply search books list for given id and returns the book object if found
    this.get = function(id) {
        for(i in books) {
            if( books[i].id == id) {
                return books[i];
            }
        }
    }

 //iterate through books list and delete book if found
    this.delete = function (id) {
        for (i in books) {
            if (books[i].id == id) {
                books.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

 //simply returns the books list
    this.list = function () {
        return books;
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#viewBook"> View Book </a></li>
                <li><a href="#addBook"> Add Book </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>       

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function assigned to `$scope.edit` seems to be missing a closed brace, does that fix your issue?

Comment: I think the closing brace is there, just a little ways down.

Comment: It might also be helpful to organize all of this code on an online code sharing site like Codepen to help speed up the process of looking at and debugging what's going on here.

Comment: @TaylorAckley ah, yep! I keep thinking the `addbook` property is a method. You're correct.

Comment: I started a jsfiddle for others to work on here: https://jsfiddle.net/acuhzr2L/3/

I think because you're using such an old version of Angular (1.0.7) you might be swimming against the grain quite hard here, especially because you're using Angular-route from the 1.2.x line, so there's a mismatch right there that might be causing you issues.